# Random letters in C++ struct

Tags: c++, class, random, struct, letters

So I have a structure I'm making, which I can also make a class, but when I try to get the properties of them...it gives me random letters. Like completely random. I'm seeing stuff like "(▌ ¶∞♥!¶↑♥!¶≤    ≈ ¶⌠  ☻!¶≈   Ç┌ ¶√   Φ`◄¶ ◄▬¶Ç┌ ¶√   Ç☻V♫√   ╨┘ ¶⌠   ╨┘ ¶⌠   0│".

I've trimmed it down to something completely basic, and I'm still clueless as to why it's doing this.

```
struct Example
{
    const char* Whatever = "Hello";
};
```

And when I do this

```
Example* exampleObj;
print(exampleObj->Whatever);
```

It brings up the random letters. The random letters vary from execution to execution of the program.

Comment: exampleObj is just a pointer that isn't pointing at anything.  So you are accessing a random part of memory. Try: `Example* exampleObj = new Example;`

Comment: I thought they were the same thing, but two different ways to do it. I've tried it out just now but it's still not working, unfortunately.

Comment: You are also not terminating the string.

Comment: Use a regular object. Forget about unnecessary pointers.

Comment: Do I simply append \0 to the strings? How would I also do this for numbers? @rekire it says the expression must have a class type when I replace the -> with a period. Chris, I need to use pointers for the library I am using.

Comment: Forget my comment I missed that it is a pointer type.

Comment: C and C++ have very specific rules about how and when objects are initialized.  If you don't ensure that objects are initialized, then you'll get very unpredictable results.

Comment: @GREnvoy: the string is terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer is a variable that holds the address in memory were an object resides. So declaring a pointer is not enough, you also need to create something for it to point at. That means you need to set aside some memory in-which you can put your object.

```
Example* exampleObj; // at the moment exampleObj contains spurious data
```

That is just a pointer. But you have not created anything for it to point at. If you try accessing it you are accessing spurious garbage!

So to allocate a chunk of memory containing a valid object you need to use `new` like this:

```
Example* exampleObj = new Example; // new returns a chunk of valid memory
```

Now the pointer is assigned a valid memory address that contains the object you just created using `new`.

**NOTE:**

There is often no need to allocate your objects manually using `new`. Instead you can use an `automatic` variable rather than a pointer:

```
Example exampleObj; // note no * means its not a pointer but a whole object
```

**SOLUTION:**

So we have 2 ways to solve your problem. Create a `new` object and assign its address to your pointer or create an `automatic` object:

```
// Solution 1:
Example* exampleObj = new Example; // Must remember to delete (smart pointer?)
print(exampleObj->Whatever);

// Solution 2 (usually MUCH better)
Example exampleObj;
print(exampleObj.Whatever); // note: uses . rather than ->
```

Comment: Thanks. This explained it, and I've got it down.

Comment: Make sure that in example 1 you delete exampleObj.